# Calculate $\int_{-1}^{-ln2} 6$ $te^{-t} dt$ . Simplify your answer. Your answer should not have any $e$’s in it.

Tags: integration

Calculate $\int_{-1}^{-\ln2} 6te^{-t} \, dt$ . Simplify your answer. Your answer should not have any $e$’s in it.

**My attempt**

I took $t=u$ and then differentiated with respect to $x.$

$dt=du$

$$\int_{-1}^{-\ln2} 6ue^{-u} \,du$$

But, I am stuck, can anyone explain how to solve this

Comment: How are $t$ and $x$ related?

Comment: You merely changed the name of a variable from $t$ to $u. \qquad$

Comment: well, if $t=f(x)$ at least tell us what is this $f(x)$ ? you actually replaced $dx$ with $dt$ which apparently have no relation at all

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to calculate $\int_{-1}^{-\ln2} 6te^{-t} \, dt$.

Integrate by parts !